# Add data to a database, without physical access to the server machine

Tags: sql-server

I have two computers in a client / server architecture. The server runs SQL Server. The client has to provide an interface to insert data to this database.

I know that this can be achieved with Microsoft Access forms but I lack the time to do it. Is there any free software that can do this?

Comment: How much faster do you want it? You didn't specify the format and nature of the data?

Comment: What do you mean faster? The data will be numbers at a small range. Let's say 001-650.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll take time no matter what software you use.

You should at least be able to install the SQL Server Management Studio (if you're running Microsoft SQL Server) and use that to write a query that'll insert your required data. This program is freely available from microsoft.

UPDATE more information:

Install the Management Studio on your own computer and connect to the database(s) on the SQL server using the Studio.

Then you should be able to run queries and add/update data in the databases as you desire using the Studio.

However, if you already have Access on your computer, it will probably be a better way to do this. The Management Studio was meant as a way to manage the databases and servers, and its query capability is only incidental. Access was meant as a way to interact with the data in databases, and so lacks management function.

UPDATE instructions for inserting data using SQL Management Studio:

First, I will assume you know SQL. If you don't know SQL you should not attempt this. I will not provide actual code you can simply copy and paste into the correct field.

Second, it will be easiest if you already have the data you need to insert entered in a table with the same basic structure as the table on the SQL server you will be updating.

With the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio installed on your computer, you will need to authenticate to the server/database, then in the Object Explorer, expand Databases.

Select the Database you wish to update, right click and select New Query. There are no wizards here. You will be presented with a blank sheet in which to write your query.

Use an INSERT or UPDATE query to add the records from the table to the database.

NOTE: This can also be done via PowerShell, which may be better if you'll need to do this process regularly. Simply create a staging database where you enter the data you'll want to insert into the database on the server, write a powershell script and save it that imports this data into the database, and run it whenever you need to.

Comment: I have already done it. :)

Comment: Did that allow you to add data?

Comment: Remotely? How? Thats my question :)

Comment: I still dont get it dude :s How will the "remote value" be entered to the table? All the stuff you say are correct but basics and already known/done :)

Comment: Umm, create table and import? Or a simple insert statement?

Comment: Re-elabourate. You have data on your current client PC, and need to insert it on the server. Is the data you need to enter somewhere already or is it just written out and still need to be entered?

Comment: Luke, are you asking me to elaborate or peraueb1989?

Comment: @Luke, I will wait for a human client to give me some instructions to enter them. So I need an interface to pass them in a user-friendly way. A good way will be php or access forms but I dont have the time to do it. I prefer something ready and more stable.

Comment: @music2myear I was talking to the OP but put this under the wrong comment

Comment: Powershell? I will take a look. So we have php forms, access forms and powershell. Thank you :)